# flatten complicated nested Json file with a lot of list of dictionary with same key ( "key", "value")

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, flatten, nested-json

I have a complicated json file that take me a lot of time to make it in Excel format, I do my best but i think I miss something so can someone help please,

the json file is below and my script did half of work :

json file :
{"logFormatVersion": "log_security_v3", "data": [
{
"logAlertUid": "a2fee3b7e2824c",
"request": {
"body": "",
"cookies": [
{
"key": "info_1",
"value": "info_2"
},
{
"key": "info_3",
"value": "info_4"
},
{
"key": "info_5",
"value": "info_6"
}
],
"headers": [
{
"key": "Host",
"value": "ip_address"
},
{
"key": "Accept-Charset",
"value": "iso-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.9,*;q=0.1"
},
{
"key": "Accept-Language",
"value": "info_7"
},
{
"key": "Connection",
"value": "Keep-Alive"
},
{
"key": "Referer",
"value": "info_8"
}
],
"hostname": "FQDN",
"ipDst": "Y.Y.Y.Y",
"ipSrc": "X.X.X.X",
"method": "GET",
"path": "/xampp/cgi.cgi",
"portDst": 443,
"protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
"query": "",
"requestUid": "info_9"
},
"websocket": [],
"context": {
"tags": "",
"geoipCode": "",
"geoipName": "",
"applianceName": "name_device",
"applianceUid": "18539",
"backendHost": "ip_address",
"backendPort": 80,
"reverseProxyName": "FQDN",
"reverseProxyUid": "info_10",
"tunnelName": "info_11",
"tunnelUid": "6d531c",
"workflowName": "name-workflow",
"workflowUid": "77802"
},
"events": [
{
"eventUid": "e62d8b",
"tokens": {
"date": "time",
"matchingParts": [
{
"part": "info_17",
"partKey": "info_18",
"partKeyOperator": "info_19",
"partKeyPattern": "info_20",
"partKeyMatch": "info_21",
"partValue": "info_21",
"partValueOperator": "info_22",
"partValuePatternUid": "info_23",
"partValuePatternName": "info_24",
"partValuePatternVersion": "00614",
"partValueMatch": "info_25",
"attackFamily": "info_26",
"riskLevel": 80,
"riskLevelOWASP": 8,
"cwe": "CWE-name"
}
],
"reason": "info_27",
"securityExceptionConfigurationUids": [
"info_28"
],
"securityExceptionMatchedRuleUids": [
"info_24"
]
}
},
{
"eventUid": "e62d8b",
"tokens": {
"date": "time",
"matchingParts": [
{
"part": "info_17",
"partKey": "info_18",
"partKeyOperator": "info_19",
"partKeyPattern": "info_20",
"partKeyMatch": "info_21",
"partValue": "info_21",
"partValueOperator": "info_22",
"partValuePatternUid": "info_23",
"partValuePatternName": "info_24",
"partValuePatternVersion": "00614",
"partValueMatch": "info_25",
"attackFamily": "info_26",
"riskLevel": 80,
"riskLevelOWASP": 8,
"cwe": "CWE-name"
}
],
"reason": "info_27",
"securityExceptionConfigurationUids": [
"info_28"
],
"securityExceptionMatchedRuleUids": [
"info_24"
]
}
}

```
 ],
"timestampImport": null,
"timestamp": "info30",
"uid": "AYYm"
```

}
]}

cordially

my script is like that :

```
import json
import pandas as pd 

with open("eventlogs.json", "r") as f:
    objectfile = json.load(f)
    data = objectfile["data"]

df =pd.DataFrame(data)
df_request = pd.json_normalize(df["request"])
df_headers = pd.DataFrame(df_request["headers"])
df_headers = df_headers.explode("headers")
df_headers[["header-key", "header-value"]] = df_headers["headers"].apply(pd.Series)
df_headers.drop("headers", axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.drop("request", axis=1)
new_df = pd.concat([df, df_request, df_headers], axis=1)

new_df.to_excel("all-data.xlsx", index=False)
```

> if you execute the script it give a result like this :
> [result without flatten "events" columns and "cookies"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cevNb.png)
> with a lot of line.

like I said the result is not really nice specially when I want to have result like this :
[Dream - File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKZlw.png)

I will be very thankful if you can help with idea to arrive to flatten this json to excel with multiindexed columns .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use further `json_normalize()` calls on the `event` and `cookies` columns to "flatten" them.

As an alternative, you could try something like this which attempts to flatten everything "automatically":

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path


def _json_flatten(data):
    rows = []
    parents = set()
    for parent, children in data:
        if isinstance(children, dict):
            row = {}
            for name, child in children.items():
                key = (parent,) + (name if isinstance(name, tuple) else (name,))
                row.setdefault(key, []).append(child)
            rows.append(row)
            parents.add(parent)
        if isinstance(children, list) and len(children) > 0:
            if all(isinstance(child, dict) for child in children):
                if set(children[0]) == set().union(*children):
                    row = {}
                    for name in children[0]:
                        key = (parent,) + (name if isinstance(name, tuple) else (name,))
                        for child in children:
                            if len(children) == 1:
                                row[key] = child[name]
                            else:
                                row.setdefault(key, []).append(child[name])
                    rows.append(row)
                    parents.add(parent)
    data = dict(data)
    for parent in parents:
        del data[parent]
    for row in rows:
        data.update(row)

    return {
        (key,) if not isinstance(key, tuple) else key: value
        for key, value in data.items()
    }


rows = json.loads(
    json.dumps(json.loads(Path("json/eventlog.json").read_bytes())["data"]),
    object_pairs_hook=_json_flatten,
)

if isinstance(rows, dict):
    rows = [rows]

rows = [
    {
        key: value[0] if (isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 1) else value
        for key, value in row.items()
    }
    for row in rows
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)

print(df)
```

Exploding the request headers:

```
columns = [ ("request", "headers", name) for name in ("key", "value") ]
df.explode(columns)[columns]
```

```
  (request, headers, key)       (request, headers, value)
0                    Host                      ip_address
0          Accept-Charset  iso-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.9,*;q=0.1
0         Accept-Language                          info_7
0              Connection                      Keep-Alive
0                 Referer                          info_8
```

Comment: Cool and perfect, i 'm still looking for a way to do it just by pandas, because sometimes the device send a json data (eventlog) with some change in key and it gives errors...

my goal is to have multi-indexed columns in my output file, I tried aspose web application  to convert json to Excel and it work perfectly, so I work to find the best way to match their file output.

Comment: If you have a JSON example that causes `_json_flatten` to error - feel free to add it to the question and I can fix it and/or attempt to provide a more pandas-focused answer.